# Java Platforms - What are available as of now?

Tags: java, jvm, platform

I was going through [Bill Venners book](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/platindepP.html) that describes about JVM... I could see some references about various Java platform:

- the Java Personal Platform (for
  consumer devices)
- the Java Embedded
  Platform (for embedded devices)
- the Java Card Platform (for SmartCards)

I thought of looking at details of these platform on Oracle site, I could see details about the [Embedded platform](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/overview/index.html), but there is nothing I could see about the Personal/Card platform. Is the information provided in the book stale?Or am I missing something?

I would just like to see specification/System requirements for various Java platform including 'Embedded', 'Card', 'Personal' and any other platform available in the market?

Comment: Yes, it is stale. In general the platform-specific details in any programming book that is *more than 10 years old*, as this one is, should be considered probably out-of-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.. Following Oracle's website I could see list of Platforms/SDKs available in Java.

Apart from SE, ME and EE, there are:

- Java Embedded
- Java FX
- Java Card
- Java TV